# Netbeans JavaSE project works fine when executed but not the .jar builded

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm trying to build a .jar to deploy my JavaSE application using Netbeans 8.2. Even though the program works well when executing in the IDE, the .jar generated doesn't work : the GUI never shows up and a "javaw.exe" run in background (seen in the task manager).

Is this a known issue ? If so, is there a fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem : the relatives paths are broken when executing the .jar since it is generated in "myProject\dist" and when executed in Netbeans it's using the folder "myProject\src".

If you have the same problem, I recommand executing the .jar using the cmd, that way errors are shown !